# Rails 3.2 Can't mass-assign protected attributes: r

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Rails 3.2.X. This is a has_one relationship.

Everything seems buttoned up here:

```
class P < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :r
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :r
  attr_accessible :s, :r_attributes
end

class R < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :a, :b, :c
  belongs_to :p
end
```

What's posted from the form

```
"p"=>{"s"=>"5/6/2012", "r"=>{"a"=>"hello", "b"=>"world", "c"=>""}}
```

Shortened P Form:

```
<%= form_for(@p) do |f| %>
<%= render :partial => "r/form", :locals => { :p_form => f, :r => @p.r } %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Shortened R Form Partial

```
<%= p_form.fields_for(r) do |fr| %>
```

If I create R like this R.new(params[p][r])  it works fine.
If I create P like this P.new(params[p])
I get can't mass assign protected attributes for R (even though it works independently)
You'll notice I have included r_attributes as accessible.

The correct answer as pointed out below is

```
<%= promotion_form.fields_for(:r) do |fr| %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form should post `r_attributes`, not `r`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: interesting, you're right, but I'm using fields_for and it's generating r, not r_attributes. Why would that be the case?

Comment: So I thought you could pass R to the fields_for form.  Turns out a string literal with the prefix r_attributes is what should be passed.  Although it seems from the docs that you can pass an object so it's unclear to me why that wasn't working in the first place.

Comment: Have you `@p.build_r` in your controller? If yes, you need use: `p_form.fields_for :r do |fr|`. I made a small example: https://github.com/eicca/attrs_test/blob/master/app/views/customers/_form.html.erb.  Also, refer this article: http://railstic.com/2009/06/nested-object-forms-with-has_one-relation/

Comment: I do have @p.build_r in my controller.  I first had p_form.fields_for p.r do |fr|. That didn't work. So then I tried p_form.fields_for :r do |fr|.  That didn't work either (although now it is, so I've updated the answer to reflect it).  When I switched it to :r_attributes...it worked.  But I'm switching back to just :r